# String.Format HTML

Tags: c#, html, string.format

string.format creates a very odd result on the html below. I believe it is something to do with the inline if block but I haven't figured it out yet. Please help!

```
String.Format(@"<input type='text' 
                       name='PostalCode' 
                       id='PostalCode' 
                       onfocus='if(this.value == '{0}') 
                                {{ this.value = ''; }}' 
                       value='{1}' 
                       class='enter-postal' />", 
              "Enter Postal Code", "Enter Postal Code")
```

Comment: What do you mean by *odd*? It produces exactly what you told it to produce.

Comment: What is it doing, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: You're using `'` inside your javascript code even if it's used as delimiter: use `"` (and escape it). Moreover I'd suggest to write a helper class to build a HTML tag with attributes...

Comment: You could avoid the whole problem by just not defining HTML through string literals.  There are generally better ways to go about this, such as having some form of markup file or template that you use instead.  If you're able to write the HTML in a proper HTML editor then mistakes like this become apparent, and you also don't need to deal with the issues of having multiple tiers of character escaping.

Comment: For something that simple why not just hardcode the 'Enter Postal Code' into the string - this will confuse you less with ' and " and escaping. Also you don't need to use {0} and {1} if the replacement strings are the same - just use {0} and only one instance of "Enter Postal Code"

Comment: Tbh, I'm not entirely sure what he's trying to accomplish, but am i wrong to think we shouldn't be comparing strings with ==?

Comment: @TheC4Fox I guess it's some sort of home-made textbox with placeholder support (_type text here_). String comparison with '==' in JavaScript is not such bad.

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing strange that I can see, so without knowing what you expect, I'm not sure what the problem is.

I do note a bug in `onfocus='if(this.value == '{0}') {{ this.value = ''; }}'` in that you've got single quotes in the attribute, and also the JS, which won't work. Try:

```
String.Format(@"<input type='text' name='PostalCode' id='PostalCode' onfocus=""if(this.value == '{0}') {{ this.value = ''; }}"" value='{1}' class='enter-postal' />",
"Enter Postal Code", "Enter Postal Code")
```

With variables rather than literals, you'd also want to do `.Replace("'", "\\'")` so that you don't end up with much the same issue due to an apostrophe in the data.

Answer (score 2):

Here try this one:

```
String.Format(@"<input type='text' name='PostalCode' id='PostalCode' onfocus='if(this.value == ""{0}"") {{ this.value = """"; }}' value='{1}' class='enter-postal' />", "Enter Postal Code", "Enter Postal Code")
```

Comment: @TheC4Fox strictly, **different** escape characters needed; to escape `"`, one uses `""`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onFocus` attribute, use escaped double quotes.

```
String.Format(@"<input type='text' 
                       name='PostalCode' 
                       id='PostalCode' 
                       onfocus=\"if(this.value == '{0}') 
                            {{ this.value = ''; }}\" value='{1}' 
                       class='enter-postal' />", 
              "Enter Postal Code", "Enter Postal Code")
```